# What should I call each book in a series of similarly-themed books?

Tags: word-choice

I am putting together a 'playbook' which contains resources related to a key growth driver for the operations team of my company.

It is a series of playbooks designed to provide resources / guidelines / standards. So the first release had foundational stuff, the second has the latest priorities, the next one will have info on capital investments and so on.

In the accompanying email, I was planning to say:

> We present to you the latest edition of our very own xxx Playbook - #2 in a series of planned Playbooks designed to support you in your market’s priorities with xxx and yyy

**My question is:** Is the word "Edition" suitable in this context? The content is different from the first issue however it revolves around the same main item (the business growth driver). Or is "Issue" a more suitable word please?

I am not looking for words like trilogy, tetralogy etc. FYI, this playbook is released quarterly. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: What about "installment"?

Comment: Edition is not the best choice, it primarily means a revision of a previous work.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this kind of writing, but since each is themed differently but related, I thing something like installment is good. Otherwise you could try the English Stack Exchange and see if it fits there.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, edition would indicate that each installment supersedes the previous installment.  If that's the case, then yes, edition is the right word.

Some options:

**Volume** or **book** helps install the idea that this is a continuing series.

**Issue** or **installment** carries a connotation of disposability, like the issues of a magazine.

From what you describe, I think “volume” is the best choice to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 'omnibus', but that only qualifies if you publish all 'playbooks' into a single compilation. If it's quarterly, then you can compile the x4 'playbooks' into a year/financial year, and then call it 'xxx Omnibus 2020'?